# how to make relation between two variables linked by one using perl,similar to metabolic networks

Tags: perl

Lets say i have generated some random alphabets and random numbers

```
A 1
Z 2
C 3
L 2
E 4
```

and similarly another set

```
1 K
4 I
2 P
5 R
6 S
7 U
```

Now we can find `2` is linked to `Z` and `L` in the first case and similarly `2` is linked to `P` in the second set
from this we can say `Z` and `L` are connected to `P`
so intially i have generated the first two steps. I am a little confused how to proceed with rest?

Comment: What does "connected to" mean?

Comment: @tarakaramji: I think you are simplifying the problem too much. Please explain the "bigger picture", as your data structure doesn't look like a good choice for the operations you want to perform.

Comment: in more simple words...the code u given is just wonderful, but u have predefined the hash, but i want it to be random.!!anywayz the problem is fixed given..the code given by below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Graph](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Graph) module can help. In fact, concepts from [Graph Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) are the right way to think about these sorts of problems instead of thrashing around with hashes and arrays trying to re-solve already solved problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Graph::Directed;
use Set::CrossProduct;

my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

my %first = qw(A 1 Z 2 C 3 L 2 E 4);
my %second = qw(1 K 4 I 2 P 5 R 6 S 7 U);

for my $h (\ (%first, %second) ) {
    $g->add_edge($_, $h->{$_}) for keys %$h;
}

print "All weakly connected components\n";

for my $wcc ( $g->weakly_connected_components ) {
    print "[@$wcc]\n";
}

my $it = Set::CrossProduct->new([ [keys %first], [values %second]]);

print "Connectedness tests\n";

while (my $case = $it->get) {
    my $is_connected = $g->same_weakly_connected_components(@$case);
    printf(
        "%s are %s in the same weakly connected component\n",
        "[@$case]", $is_connected ? '' : 'not'
    );
}
```

### Output

#### All weakly connected components

```
[R 5]
[E 4 I]
[K 1 A]
[2 Z L P]
[S 6]
[7 U]
[C 3]
```

#### Connectedness tests

```
[Z S] are not in the same weakly connected component
[Z I] are not in the same weakly connected component
[Z K] are not in the same weakly connected component
[Z U] are not in the same weakly connected component
[Z P] are  in the same weakly connected component
[Z R] are not in the same weakly connected component
[A S] are not in the same weakly connected component
[A I] are not in the same weakly connected component
[A K] are  in the same weakly connected component
[A U] are not in the same weakly connected component
[A P] are not in the same weakly connected component
[A R] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C S] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C I] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C K] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C U] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C P] are not in the same weakly connected component
[C R] are not in the same weakly connected component
[E S] are not in the same weakly connected component
[E I] are  in the same weakly connected component
[E K] are not in the same weakly connected component
[E U] are not in the same weakly connected component
[E P] are not in the same weakly connected component
[E R] are not in the same weakly connected component
[L S] are not in the same weakly connected component
[L I] are not in the same weakly connected component
[L K] are not in the same weakly connected component
[L U] are not in the same weakly connected component
[L P] are  in the same weakly connected component
[L R] are not in the same weakly connected component
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to recommend a wildly different approach that may be easier to think about if you are  more familiar with SQL than perl, you can look into [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV-0.33/lib/DBD/CSV.pm).  You can then accomplish what you want with a simple join statement.  Just follow the example on the linked page.  If you don't know SQL than you are probably better off with a hash of arrays as already posted.  I'll post actual code when I get to a machine that has DBD::CSV installed...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you need is all the relationships like the one you have shown us?

Here is an example program which does that. Please explain if you need something different.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data1 = qw(
  A 1
  Z 2
  C 3
  L 2
  E 4
);

my %data2 = qw(
  1 K
  4 I
  2 P
  5 R
  6 S
  7 U
);

#  Convert to arrays indexed by the numbers
#
my @data1;
push @{ $data1[$data1{$_}] }, $_ for keys %data1;

my @data2;
push @{ $data2[$_] }, $data2{$_} for keys %data2;

# Find all the mappings between the datasets
#
for my $i (0 .. $#data1) {
  my $data1 = $data1[$i] or next;
  my $data2 = $data2[$i] or next;
  print "@$data1 => @$data2\n";
}
```

**output**

```
A => K
Z L => P
E => I
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my (@n,@s);

sub generate_random_string
{
    my @chars=('a'..'z');
    my $random_string;
    $random_string.=$chars[rand @chars];
    return $random_string;
}

print "one\n";
foreach(1..5)
{
    my $range = 10;
    my $random_number = int(rand($range));
    push (@n,$random_number);
    my $random_string=&generate_random_string;
    push(@s,$random_string);
    print $random_number." ".$random_string."\n";
}
my (@nn,@ss);
print "two\n";
foreach(1..6)
{
    my $range = 10;
    my $random_number = int(rand($range));
    push (@nn,$random_number);
    my $random_string=&generate_random_string;
    push(@ss,$random_string);
    print $random_number." ".$random_string."\n";
}

my %h1;

# prepare data
for (my $i=0;$i<=$#n;$i++)
{
    $h1{$i}{'a'}=$s[$i];
    $h1{$i}{'i'}=$n[$i];
}
my %h2;
for (my $i=0;$i<=$#nn;$i++)
{
    $h2{$i}{'a'}=$ss[$i];
    $h2{$i}{'i'}=$nn[$i];
}
# end prepare data

my %result;

foreach (keys %h2)
{
    my $letter=$h2{$_}{'a'};
    my $number=$h2{$_}{'i'};
    my @rarr;
    foreach (keys %h1)
    {
    if ($h1{$_}{'i'}==$number)
        {
            push(@rarr,$h1{$_}{'a'});
        }
    }
    if ($#rarr>=0)
    {
        @{$result{$letter}}=@rarr;
    }
    @rarr=undef;
}
foreach (keys %result)
{
    print join(',',@{$result{$_}})." connected to ".$_."\n";
}
```

result:

```
one
8 s
2 g
6 z
7 g
7 a
two
7 e
8 w
3 r
1 c
0 t
7 h
a,g connected to e
s connected to w
a,g connected to h
```

Comment: The program u have given is very specific....wht i have gnerated is random...it should be true to any variable...lets consider if it is not 'P' but some other connection involved so in it....

Comment: my input is actually a random.the input i have given above is random. so it keeps on changing..it shouldn't be a specific once....

Comment: i mean, what i need type of input arrays. (script fix to all)

Comment: foreach(1..5)
{
  my $range = 10;

  my $random_number = int(rand($range));

  push (@n,$random_number);
sub generate_random_string
{
 my @chars=('a'..'z');
 my $random_string;
# 
  $random_string.=$chars[rand @chars];
 
 return $random_string;
}
my $random_string=&generate_random_string;
push(@s,$random_string); using this i have generated first 2 arrays.. similarly the other 2 arrays are generated. but when i apply ur program (later half)after creating the arrays..its not working??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10526/discussion-between-tarakaramji-and-askovpen)

Comment: @tarakaramji: please don't just disappear and solve the problem out of sight. Several people have worked to answer the question and we deserve to be involved.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to solve your issue using hashes of arrays. For example if you know already that Z, L and P are conncted via 2 and you have a data structure like this

```
my %hash_of_arrays = ( '2' => ['Z', 'L', 'P' ]);
```

already. and now you find out that 'Q' is also connected to '2' you would

```
push(@{hash_of_arrays{'2'}}, 'Q');
```

Other situation is when you encounter a new $key you may want to insert a new array into the hash:

```
my $array = []
$hash_of_arrays{$key} = $array
```

hope i understood you right...

Comment: not exactly!!but initially i have generated                             A 
Z 
C 
L 
E and after random numbers to them. i thought keeping the alphabets into keys and corresponding numbers into values.....similar thing is doen wen i generate a next set which is just opposite. the alphabets will be considered as values and numbers considered as keys, so after which comparison has to be made!!hope u understood now...

Answer (score 0):

You would want a hash of arrays, which will require the use of array references.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

my @a1 = qw( 1 K 4 I 2 P 5 R K 6 S 7 U );

my %HoA1;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @a1 - 1; $i++ ) {
    unless( defined $HoA1{ $a1[$i] } ) {
        $HoA1{ $a1[$i] } = [];
        push @{$HoA1{ $a1[$i] }}, $a1[$i+1];
    } else {
        push @{$HoA1{ $a1[$i] }}, $a1[$i+1];
    }
}

for my $key ( sort keys %HoA1 ) {
    print "$key: @{$HoA1{ $key }} \n";
}
```

Comment: Ah, the original formatting of your question threw me off... the same method should work, but you'll have to build $HoA1 a little differently.

Comment: But there is a repetion of the first variable in sense...r 
r 
n 
this is generated by ur program after inserting into keys           g 
r 
g
r 
n
g 
r
r

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid that I didn't understand that, can you clarify?

Comment: the above program is not exactly generating the what i mentioned above.??